# como soluciono el mensaje que me aparece en chrome "no se admite el indicador de linea de comandos (--ignore-certificate-errors)

Tags: google-chrome

estoy realizando pruebas automatizadas con watir-webdriver y al intentar reproducirlas me aparece el mensaje no se admite el indicador de linea de comandos (`--ignore-certificate-errors`) en la ventana del chrome.

copio un código de prueba dado que me aparece con cualquier prueba que quiera ejecutar

Comment: Tengo el mismo problema, espero una respuesta pronto